# ActionCable Multiple Channels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I am new to ActionCable and I was wondering how to set up multiple room channels for a chat. I was looking it up and still cant figure it out. I want to make each user have their own room channel is there a way to do this? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking at this and is wondering the same thing this helped me out a lot.

http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/rails-5-action-cable-with-multiple-chatroom-subscriptions/